# Flink1.17 web ui interface metrics consistently display loading

Tags: apache-flink

Attempting to rule out common math jar package conflicts, this issue still persists, but sometimes it doesn't work and some metrics may be displayed, Also attempting to exclude the Flink metrics core package

[image: flink ui]

I hope all the big shots can solve it